# Using Javascript to create html custom Tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
class Headers extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const selected = this.props.selectedPane;
    const headers = this.props.panes.map((pane, index) => {
      const title = pane.title;
      const klass = index === selected ? 'active' : '';

      return (
        <li
          key={index}
          className={klass}
          onClick={() => this.props.onTabChosen(index)}>
          {title}{' '}
        </li>
      );
    });
    
    return (
      <ul className='tab-header'>
        {headers}
      </ul>

    );
 }
}

export default class Tabs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedPane: 0
    };
    this.selectTab = this.selectTab.bind(this);
  }

  selectTab(num) {
    this.setState({selectedPane: num});
  }

  render() {
    const pane = this.props.panes[this.state.selectedPane];

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Tabs</h1>
        <div className='tabs'>
        <Headers
            selectedPane={this.state.selectedPane}
            //onTabChosen={this.selectTab}
            panes={this.props.panes}>
          </Headers>
          <div className='tab-content'>
            <article>
                hellooooo
              {pane.content}
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm currently creating a 3 tab section where if you click on a tab, it gives you a new pane.

When looking at the render function I see a custom tag called `Headers`.

I know it coming from the `Headers` class at the beginning, but how does that format work? Is that a custom tag we building?

Also when looking at its properties such as `onTabChosen`, when it is deleted in the render method (for learning purposes) and I click on a selected tab, an error comes up saying

> "_this.props.onTabChosen is not a function".

`this.props.onTabChosen(index)..` was written in the Headers class but not as a function correct?

I guess because I am also confused on how `this.props.onTabChosen(index)` works since `onTabChosen` was never declared anywhere, just input after props.

Comment: When posting a question here, then you should limit yourself to one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

> When looking at the render function I see a custom tag called "Headers".

That is not a [custom tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements). That is a React Component.

> I know it coming from the Headers class at the beginning, but how does that format work?

`Headers` is either a function or a class (i.e. a constructor function).

The function will be called and the first argument passed to it will be an object with properties and values that match the props on the JSX element.

---

If you're going to use React then **read a tutorial**, this is very introductory level stuff for the framework.

It is covered very early on in both the [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_getting_started#how_does_react_use_javascript) and the official [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#overview).

> I guess because I am also confused on how this.props.onTabChosen(index) works since onTabChosen was never declared anywhere, just input after props.

It was declared, just not in the piece of code you shared.

Comment: `It was declared, just not in the piece of code you shared.` is that really true? I don't really work with react. But doesn't the `onTabChosen` called in `onClick={() => this.props.onTabChosen(index)}` result in the shown error, when the `onTabChosen={this.selectTab}'` in the `<Header …>`  is commented out? So that `onTabChosen={this.selectTab}` is actually the declaration (forwarding to another function)?